# AS3 mask weird result

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, mask

I'm playing around with dynamic masking for part of a puzzle game I'm making.

I've got a test puzzle with 6 pieces. The puzzle exists out of 3 layers:

- black shape = this is where you put your pieces
- finished pieces = this is a layer showing the combined result of found pieces
- loose pieces = can be moved into place.

The black shape is no problem, that's just a simple color transform on the result sprite.

When I combine the finished pieces in one sprite, I notice smaller than hairline gaps between the pieces. This doesn't look too good, so I've been thinking of a way around this:

One way I thought of was to put a mask on a complete result sprite so that only the found pieces are visible. I would add a 1px border around the pieces to avoid the hairline gaps.

So, I started playing around with masks:

```
// test
var test: Sprite = new TestSprite() as Sprite;
test.x = test.y = 100;
addChild(test);

// puzzle pieces            
var pieces: Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>;
pieces.push(new TurtlePiece1());
pieces.push(new TurtlePiece2());
//pieces.push(new TurtlePiece3());
//pieces.push(new TurtlePiece4());
pieces.push(new TurtlePiece5());
pieces.push(new TurtlePiece6());

// finished locations for each piece
var points: Vector.<Point> = new Vector.<Point>;
points.push(new Point(0.3, 7.25));
points.push(new Point(110.35, 0));
//points.push(new Point(98.25, 52.6));
//points.push(new Point(23.95, 69.30));
points.push(new Point(157.25, 61.95));
points.push(new Point(146.7, 100.70));

var mask: Sprite = new Sprite();
for (var i: int = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
    pieces[i].x = points[i].x;
    pieces[i].y = points[i].y;
    mask.addChild(pieces[i]);
}
test.mask = mask;
```

The full shape and the mask shape look like this:

[image: full image and mask shape]

After applying the mask it looks like this:

[image: masked image]

I have tried caching as bitmap, without result. Anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Tnx in advance,

With kind regards,
Jeroen

Comment: looks like a cacheAsBitmapMatrix problem.  are you calling that?

Comment: I'm not calling that. I have tried setting cacheABitmap=true for the mask and the test sprite without luck. I haven't tried cacheAsBitmapMatrix.

Comment: Okay, I now tried to set cacheAsBitmapMatrix on the mask and the test sprites. Same result.

Comment: Select the entire mask and hit ctrl+b a dozen times. Should ensure no vectors are overlapping (which is the case when you import graphics). Might be the cause.

Comment: This is done dynamically using AS3 only. I did what you suggested earlier as a test, but it yielded the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see what you're attempting to do but i'm not sure why it's not working for you.  i've created a similar program an it works as expected:

```
//Imports
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Sprite;

//Draw Background Rect
var backgroundRect:Shape = new Shape();
backgroundRect.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1.0);
backgroundRect.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
backgroundRect.graphics.endFill();

addChild(backgroundRect);

//Build Mask From Circles
var backgroundMask:Sprite = new Sprite();

var circleA:Shape = circle(50, 0xFF0000);
circleA.x = 50;
circleA.y = 50;

var circleB:Shape = circle(50, 0x00FF00);
circleB.x = 100;
circleB.y = 50;

var circleC:Shape = circle(50, 0x0000FF);
circleC.x = 150;
circleC.y = 75;

backgroundMask.addChild(circleA);
backgroundMask.addChild(circleB);
backgroundMask.addChild(circleC);

addChild(backgroundMask);

//Assign Mask
backgroundRect.mask = backgroundMask;

//Create Circle
function circle(radius:uint, color:uint):Shape
{
    var result:Shape = new Shape();
    result.graphics.beginFill(color, 1.0);
    result.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, radius);
    result.graphics.endFill();

    return result;
}
```

[image]

the only thing i can think of that the pieces you are adding to the mask sprite are overriting each other, similarly to what happens when you overlap two or more shapes within a single graphics call:

```
//Imports
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Sprite;

//Draw Circle
var circleA:Shape = circle(50, 0xFF0000);
circleA.x = 50;
circleA.y = 50;

addChild(circleA);

//Create Circle
function circle(radius:uint, color:uint):Shape
{
    var result:Shape = new Shape();
    result.graphics.beginFill(color, 1.0);
    result.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, radius);
    result.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, radius);
    result.graphics.endFill();

    return result;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Tnx for the answers. I've tried some more and couldn't get it to work properly. I've choosen to go a different road instead and it does what I want it to do: instead of glueing the pieces together to form a mask, I'm gluing the pieces together to form the pic that is shown. I tried this before, but had problems with the seams (very tiny openings). I corrected that by making the pieces 1px larger at the seams (so there is an effective overlap, avoiding holes).